# Query regarding parameters for alerting

Tags: terraform, datadog

I am trying to create a synthetic test in Datadog using terraform. There is an option to alert when synthetic test fails for a specific duration on the interface while creating a synthetic test.
[image]

This will alert only when the test fails for the duration.
I tried to find a similar parameter in the resource on the terraform documentation but can't find any
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/DataDog/datadog/latest/docs/resources/synthetics_test

Can anyone help me to find any equivalent parameter to alert when the test fails for a specific duration using terraform resource?

Answer (score 0):

There is an attribute `min_failure_duration` which can be added in the resource. The value is in seconds so if you want to create a synthetic test that alerts only when the duration of failure is >=3 min, you can add this attribute as `min_failure_duration = 180`

```
resource "datadog_synthetics_test" "test_api" {
  type    = "api"
  subtype = "http"
  request_definition {
    method = "GET"
    url    = "https://www.example.org"
  }
  request_headers = {
    Content-Type   = "application/json"
    Authentication = "Token: 1234566789"
  }
  assertion {
    type     = "statusCode"
    operator = "is"
    target   = "200"
  }
  locations = ["aws:eu-central-1"]
  options_list {
    tick_every = 900
--> min_failure_duration = 180


    retry {
      count    = 2
      interval = 300
    }

    monitor_options {
      renotify_interval = 100
    }
  }
  name    = "An API test on example.org"
  message = "Notify @pagerduty"
  tags    = ["foo:bar", "foo", "env:test"]

  status = "live"
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is in seconds.

Comment: Please elaborate more on the question as well as answer with context

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have updated the question and answer @SaikatSaha